# Suppose that $X$ is locally compact and $G$ acting on $X$ is proper. Show that the quotient $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, geometric-group-theory

Suppose that $X$ is locally compact and $G$ acting on $X$ is proper. Show that the quotient $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

I am working through some notes on Geometric Group Theory and I am having a hard time with this problem.  Some help would be great.

A topological group action $μ : G$ acts on $X$ is called proper if for every compact subsets $K_1,K_2 ⊂ X,$
￼￼￼￼the set is $\{g \in G | g(K_1)\cap K_2 \neq \emptyset \}$ contained in $G$ is compact.

Comment: What are $X$ and $G$ here and what do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: You may find the following fact useful: for any topological space $X$ (Hausdorff or not!), the quotient of $X$ by an equivalence relation $R \subseteq X \times X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $R$ is closed as a subset of $X \times X$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522654/how-to-prove-the-space-of-orbits-is-a-hausdorff-space). The proof works in the given setting.

Comment: One usually uses the following fact to prove this: suppose the action of $G$ on $X$ is proper, then for every $x\in X$ there exists an open neighbourhood (connected even) $U_x$ with compact closure such that $gU_x \cap U_x$ is nonempty iff $g$ fixes $x$ (where $g\in G$).